# Error al mostrar en mi etiqueta <img> la imagen almacenada en el storage de firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, formularios, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

Cuando hago el submmit de mi formulario, efectivamente los datos se guardan en cloud firestore.
pero si se fijan en el campo url de mi colección books el path de la url la guarda como `C:/fakepath/nombre de la imagen`. ¿No debería guardarme la url que me proporciona firestorage?
les muestro la imagen de mi colección de `Cloud Firestore`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cuando quiero mostrar la imagen en la etiqueta `<img>` me muestra este error por consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que puedo entender, no muestra la imagen en la etiqueta `<img>` porque el path de la imagen guardada en el `storage de firebase` es incorrecto.

Aca el `book-form.component.html` (solo muestro el `<input="file">` para que el código no se haga largo):

```html
<div class="row pt-4">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="card card-body pt-4">
            <h3 class="text-center"><b>Create book</b></h3>           
            <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addBook($event)">
                                       
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="text-center mb-3">
                        <img class="img" [src]="url">
                    </div>                   
                    <input type="file" class="form-control"
                    formControlName="image"
                    (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <button [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
                        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Save
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning btn-block text-white">Reset
                        <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>               
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <app-books></app-books>
    </div>    
</div>
```

aca la lógica `book-form.component.ts`

```js
export class BookFormComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  authorList$: Observable<Author[]>;
  image$: Observable<any>;
  book = {} as Book; // declaro un objeto Book vacio, no es un array
  // obteniendo año actual
  today = new Date();
  year = this.today.getFullYear();

  url = 'http://placehold.it/180';

 selectedFile = null;

  constructor(
    public bookService: BookService,
    public authorService: AuthorService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
    ) {
      // function buildForm
      this.buildForm();
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authorList$ = this.authorService.getAuthors();
   
  }

  buildForm() {
    // const numericNumberReg = '^-?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d{1,2})?$';
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      year: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(this.year)]],
      author: ['', [Validators.required]],
      category: ['', [Validators.required]],
      editorial: ['', [Validators.required]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(300)]],
      quantity: ['', [Validators.required]],
      price: [0, [Validators.required]],
      image: [''],
      state: [true]
    });
  }

  addBook(event: Event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    this.book = this.form.value;
    console.log(this.book);
    if (this.form.valid)
    {
      if (confirm('¿Esta seguro/a que desea agregar el producto?'))
      {
        // obtengo los valores del formulario
        this.book = this.form.value;
        // inserta el producto en la db firestore
        this.bookService.addBook(this.book);
        // guardo la imagen en firestorage
        this.onUploadFile();
        // para limpiar el formulario
        this.form.reset();
        this.book = {} as Book;
        //seteo la img <img> lado html
        // this.url = 'http://placehold.it/180';
        this.toastr.success('Operación exitosa', 'Producto agregado!');
      }
    }
  }

  onFileSelected(event) {
    // obtengo el archivo completo de la img (nombre, tipo, tamaño, etc..)
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    if (event.target.files.length === 0 || event.target.files[0] == null ) {
      // cuando este vacío
      }else {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.url = event.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }

  onUploadFile() {
    // obtengo solo el nombre de la imagen
    const name = this.selectedFile.name;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(name);
    // subo imagen a firestorage con el nombre y todas sus prop(tipo, tamaño, etc..)
    const task = this.storage.upload(name, this.selectedFile);

    task.snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      // finalize notifica cuando termina de subir la imagen
      finalize(() => {
        this.image$ = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
        this.image$.subscribe(url => {
          console.log(url);
          // le asigno la url de la img guardada en firestorage
          this.form.get('image').setValue(url);
        });
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
  }

}
```

Aca `books.component.html` donde muestro la imagen

```html
<li *ngFor="let book of books" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">                
        <h3><b>{{book.name}}</b></h3>
        <h5>Autor: {{book.author}}</h5>
        <h5>Año: {{book.year}}</h5>
        <img [src]="book.image" alt="">
</li>
```

y su lógica

```js
export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {

  books = [];
  
  constructor(
    public bookService: BookService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) { }

  ngOnInit () {
    this.fetchBooks();
  
  }

  fetchBooks(){
    this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe(books => {
      this.books = books;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Creo que tu problema es mas un poco de lógica por que ejecutas tu función onUploadFile, hasta después de que cargas tu registro y le añades a image el getDownloadURL cuando regresa pero para ese momento ya se actualizo tu registro

Comment: gracias por responder!, si en eso tenes razón. Eso lo cambie en la funcion addBook() puse que primeramente se ejecute la función this.onUploadFile(); pero sigue dando el mismo resultado

Comment: Revisa cuando te regresa la url de descarga ```fileRef.getDownloadURL();``` coincida con el registro que envías  en ```this.bookService.addBook(this.book);```, si no coincide puede ser por que usas un input  file y ese no te muestra la ruta de tu archivo, entonces intenta asignarlo a otro input,  o en una variable dentro de tu componente y asignarla a this.book antes de enviarla.

Comment: muestra este error: core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): UnsubscriptionError: 1 errors occurred during unsubscription:
1) InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
    at resolvePromise

Comment: tambien me fije que hay en this.book.image y lo que hay es esto: C:\fakepath\img.jpg"

Comment: Es por el input file, deja la url en una variable y asignala a this.book.image antes de enviara.

Comment: fue lo que hice, declare variable let path = ''.  despues del subscribe hice esto path = url; y this.book.image = path;  pero sigue guardandolo como fakePath

Comment: actualiza el codigo

Comment: gracias! pude lograrlo con tu idea, aunque tuve que hacer todo en una sola función, de lo contrario obtenía null en el path de la imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO! Hago todo en una sola función llamada `uploadImage(event)`, el inconveniente que tiene es que apenas se elige la imagen, la guarda en firebase storage. Intenté dividir la función en dos partes, una función que atrape la imagen con `const file = event.target.files[0];` y otra función que haga el upload a storage de firebase en la funcion `addBook()`. Pero siempre me guardaba el path de la imagen como null. Entonces opté por hacer todo en una sola función como muestro a continuación.

```js
selectedFile = null;

uploadImage(event){
    // si se eligió la imagen
    if (event.target.files.length !== 0 || event.target.files[0] != null )
     {
      // obtengo el archivo completo de la img (nombre, tipo, tamaño, etc..)
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      // obtengo solo el nombre de la imagen
      const name = file.name;
      const fileRef = this.storage.ref(name);
      // subo imagen a firestorage con el nombre y todas sus prop(tipo, tamaño, etc..)
      const task = this.storage.upload(name, file);
      task.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.image$ = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
          this.image$.subscribe(url => {
            this.selectedFile = url;
        });
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
    }
  }
```

y en el html

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- <img *ngIf="(image$ | async) as image" [src]="image"       alt=""> -->
  <input type="file" class="form-control"  formControlName="image"
 (change)="uploadImage($event)">
</div>
```